# Angular directive using value from database, interpolate and filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which I've used for texts in my app:

```
module.directive("enaText", function (textService) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            // Catching <enaText key="[key]"> and <div ena-text="[key]">
            scope.$watchCollection(function () {
                return [attributes.key, attributes.enaText];
            }, function (values) {
                var key = values[0] || values[1];

                if (!key) {
                    return;
                }

                var text = textService.get(key) || key;

                // Not using a template to easier support HTML in text value
                element.html(text || "");
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

My textService helps with getting the text in the current language from sessionStorage (initially from a database). This version of the directive works just as intended:

```
<div ena-text="page_title"></div>
```

Which gets the text with name/key "page_title" and puts it in the div.

Now I want to extend the directory to be able to use scope variables in the text strings from textService and possibly also filters. This is what I have so far:

```
module.directive("enaTextNew", function (textService, $interpolate, $parse, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            var regex = /^([^\|]*)(\|.+)?/;

            // Catching <enaText key="[key]"> and <div ena-text="[key]">
            scope.$watchCollection(function () {
                return [attributes.key, attributes.enaTextNew];
            }, function (values) {
                var expression = values[0] || values[1];

                if (!expression) {
                    return;
                }

                var match = expression.match(regex);
                var key = match[1].trim();
                var filter = match[2];

                var text = textService.get(key) || key;

                text = $interpolate(text)(scope);

                if (filter) {
                    text = scope.$eval("'" + text + "'" + filter);
                }

                // Not using a template to easier support HTML in text value
                element.html(text || "");
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

This works fine when I use it in:

```
<div ena-text-new="character_count|uppercase"></div>
```

Which gets the text `"{{count}} characters of max {{max}}"`, uses variables `count` and `max` from scope and then adds the uppercase filter. The result is for example: `"0 CHARACTERS OF MAX 100"`.

The only problem is that even though `scope.count` (or `scope.max`) is changed, it's not reflected in the result of the directive.

This specific string and the filter is just an example. Filters will propably not be necessary, I've tried without it but it didn't do any difference. But the important thing is the scope variables.

Comment: You appear to be watching _string literals_ only by the way your directive is designed. Even if you have interpolated values in your strings and they have their values changed, the watch will not re-trigger, hence your problem.

Comment: I got a comment from the user PSL where he pointed this out. But he removed his comment, so I'll answer this myself soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user [PSL](https://stackexchange.com/users/992844/psl) helped me get on the right track using http://plnkr.co/edit/ir9Ews. I made some changes to it, because a new watch would else be created every time the attributes values changed. This is what I use now:

```
module.directive("enaText", function (textService, $interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            var keyFilterRegex = /^([^\|]*)(\|.+)?/;
            var originalText;
            var filter;

            // Catching <enaText key="[key]"> and <div ena-text="[key]">
            scope.$watchCollection(function () {
                return [attributes.key, attributes.enaText];
            }, function (values) {
                var expression = values[0] || values[1];

                if (!expression) {
                    originalText = undefined;
                    filter = undefined;
                    return;
                }

                var match = expression.match(keyFilterRegex);
                originalText = textService.get(match[1]);
                filter = match[2];
            });

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return $interpolate(originalText || "")(scope);
            }, function (text) {
                if (filter) {
                    text = scope.$eval("'" + text + "'" + filter);
                }

                // Not using a template to easier support HTML in text value
                element.html(text);
            });
        }
    };
});
```